# Don't understand symbol error -- using arrays for the first time

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a program for my Java class. The instructions seem pretty straight forward to me, but I'll paste them below in case anyone interprets them differently.

Write a RainFall class that has the following field:

• an array of doubles that stores the rainfall for each of the 12 months of
the year (where the first index corresponds with January, the second with
February, etc.)

The class should also have the following methods:

• a method that returns the total rainfall for the entire year
• a method that returns the average monthly rainfall for the year
• a method that returns the month with the most rain as a string
• a method that returns the month with the least rain as a string

Demonstrate the class in a program that takes 12 doubles from the user (take the 
doubles in the order of the months of the year, the first corresponding to the 
rainfall in January, etc.). Do input validation: if the user inputs a negative
number, ignore it and continue asking them for input until you have 12
nonnegative doubles.

Once the user has given you all 12 doubles, create an instance of the RainFall
class and call its methods, printing out the total rainfall, the average
monthly rainfall, the month with the most rain, and the month with the least
rain, each on a separate line.

We were given a bit of code to start off with, which appears to be everything except for the methods. Here is what was given to us.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RainFall {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        double[] rainfall = new double[12];
        int i = 0;
        System.out.print("Enter rainfall for month 1:");

        while(i < 12){
            double rain = scanner.nextDouble();
            if(rain >= 0){
                rainfall[i] = rain;
                i++;
            }
            if(i!=12){
                System.out.print("Enter rainfall for month " + (i+1) + ":");
            }
        }

        RainFall rf = new RainFall(rainfall);
        System.out.println(rf.total());
        System.out.println(rf.average());
        System.out.println(rf.most());
        System.out.println(rf.least());

    }
    //add code here
}
```

So I put this in the area where we were supposed to add code.

```
public RainFall(double[] a) {
        rainfall = a;
}

public static double total() {
    double t = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < rainfall.length; i++) {
        t += rainfall[i];
    }
    return t;
}
public static double average() {
    double v = 0.0;
    double t = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < rainfall.length; i++) {
        t += rainfall[i];
    }
    v = t/rainfall.length;
    return v;
}
public static String most() {
    String months[]={"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                    "October", "November", "December"};
    int j = 0;
    int max = rainfall[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < rainfall.length; i++) {
        if(rainfall[i] > max) {
            max = rainfall[i];
            j = i;
        }
    }
    return months[j];
}
public static String least() {
    String months[]={"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                    "October", "November", "December"};
    int j = 0;
    int min = rainfall[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < rainfall.length; i++) {
        if(rainfall[i] < min) {
            min = rainfall[i];
            j = i;
        }
    }
    return months[j];
}
```

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me out with this. I really have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: What exactly is the question/problem? If you have an error, read it, and post it. It matters. It tells you what is wrong, and where.

Comment: You need to specify the compiler error which will say where the problem is and with what symbol.

Comment: Consider also using more meaningful variable names than `a`, `t` and `v`. It just makes it much easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access an **instance** variable from a **static method**.  You need to declare the instance variable `rainfall` before you can use it.  Also, you were missing some casts to `int` in your `min()` and `max()` functions.

Try changing the code you added to this:

```
public class RainFall {

    public double[] rainfall;


    public RainFall(double[] a) {
        this.rainfall = a;
    }

    public double total() {
        double t = 0.0;
        for(int i = 0; i < rainfall.length; i++) {
            t += rainfall[i];
        }
        return t;
    }
    public double average() {
        double v = 0.0;
        double t = 0.0;
        for(int i = 0; i < rainfall.length; i++) {
            t += rainfall[i];
        }
        v = t/rainfall.length;
        return v;
    }
    public String most() {
        String months[]={"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                        "October", "November", "December"};
        int j = 0;
        int max = (int) rainfall[0];
        for(int i = 1; i < rainfall.length; i++) {
            if(rainfall[i] > max) {
                max = (int) rainfall[i];
                j = i;
            }
        }
        return months[j];
    }
    public String least() {
        String months[]={"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                        "October", "November", "December"};
        int j = 0;
        int min = (int) rainfall[0];
        for(int i = 1; i < rainfall.length; i++) {
            if(rainfall[i] < min) {
                min = (int) rainfall[i];
                j = i;
            }
        }
        return months[j];
    }
}
```

Also learn about what `static` and `instance` mean at this Stack Exchange post: [What are the differences between class variables and instance variables in Java?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/293478/what-are-the-differences-between-class-variables-and-instance-variables-in-java).

***Happy Coding!***

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm pretty new to programming so it's hard for me to spot obvious errors. I'm finally starting to notice errors with static methods and conversions between variable types.

Comment: @SquatJohnson Mark the answer as the accepted answer if it solved your problem please :)